# Showing uib-tabset inside uibModal, height overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to show `uib-tabset` inside `uibModal` and want the tabset to fill the modal perfectly, in geeky terms , `width:100%;height:100%;`

**Tabset:-**

```
<uib-tabset id="mine-tabset" active="active">
       <uib-tab ng-repeat="tab in Tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" active="tab.active" disable="tab.disabled" ng-click="tabClicked(tab)">
         <div id = "tab-container" ng-include="tab.content"></div>
       </uib-tab>
     </uib-tabset>
```

Now to achieve my goal of filling the Modal completely, I did this:

```
.tabset, .tab-content, .tab-pane, .tabbable {
  height:100%;
}
#tab-container{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}
```

**My Problem:-**

So what I am finally getting is that the height of the Tab and its content is overflowing the Modal at the bottom of Modal.

What I came to know, I guess the reason for this is for 100% height, the height of `.nav-tabs` is also getting added to the `.tab-content`. Is this right? How to solve this?